# Unable to configure new MongoDb drivers (php_mongodb.dll) for PHP in WAMP

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp, php-mongodb

I want to work with PHP and MongoDb, but I'm not able to configure new MongoDb drivers for PHP.
I have tested with old MongoDb drivers (php_mongo.dll) it's working fine.

Steps I had done to configure new MongoDb drivers :

1] Downloaded latest mongodb drivers (php_mongodb-1.3.1-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip).

2] Copied php_mongodb.dll at both directories for safer side :

a) C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext

b) C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext

3] Added line **extension=php_mongodb.dll** at the end of php.ini @C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\php.ini

4] Restarted WAMP server and tested if drivers configured at "http://localhost:90/?phpinfo=1", But there is nothing like "mongo" there.

If I do all above steps for old drivers (php_mongo.dll) then it's showing "mongo" section at "http://localhost:90/?phpinfo=1".

**System and Application versions**

Windows 10 64 bit

WAMP Server 3.0.6

PHP 5.6.25

php_mongodb-1.3.1-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip driver

Please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong, or if something missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved, I was using "php_mongodb-1.3.1-**7.1**-ts-vc14-x64.zip" driver for both PHP versions (5.6 and 7.0).

**How to resolve this issue** : Download "php_mongodb-1.1.8-**5.6**-ts-vc11-x64.zip" extract zip and copy "php_mongodb.dll" at "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext".

Then do it same for 7.0 , download "php_mongodb-1.1.8-**7.0**-ts-vc14-x64.zip" extract zip and copy "php_mongodb.dll" at "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext".

Apart from dll version, everything else done in above steps (4 Steps in question) was prefect.

Above drivers downloaded from https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.1.8/windows, here you will have list of MongoDb drivers for PHP, along with compatible PHP version.